# displaying boolean value / invalid qualifier

Tags: vba, excel

Maybe because it's been a long day......
I don't get it.
Why does this code give me an 'invalid qualifier' msg?

```
Sub UsingBooleans()
Dim MastNameNew As Boolean
MsgBox "mastnamenew value = " & MastNameNew.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: It should be `MsgBox "mastnamenew value = " & MastNameNew`.

Comment: `MastNameNew` is Boolean variable, not an object, it doesn't have properties such as `.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

To your error : `MastNameNew` is a Boolean variable with only possible value as `"False (0)"` or `"True (1)"`. So there are no properties available for a `Boolean`.
Please find the below code
If you want answer as "False" or True Then use below code:

```
Sub UsingBooleans()
Dim MastNameNew As Boolean
MsgBox "mastnamenew value = " & MastNameNew
End Sub
```

And if you want the answer as "0" or "1" then use the below code:

```
Sub UsingBooleans()
Dim MastNameNew As Boolean
MsgBox "mastnamenew value = " & CInt(MastNameNew)
End Sub
```